# Basic Layout with display: grid (CSS Grid) for Phone, Tablet and Desktop

Tags: html, css, media-queries

has someone an working example Layout with the Requirements in the title? I also need a Main Navigation with `<nav>` which is globally used for Phone, Tablet and Desktop.

**The Following HTML5 Elements should be used for the Layout:**

```
<nav> for the Main Navigation
<header> for Title, Logos, Burger-Menue-Button
<main> for the main Content
<footer> for Footer Content
```

The Breakpoints are:

- Phones from 0px up to 599px
- Tablets from 600px up to 1023px
- Desktop all ViewPorts from a minimum of 1024px

The Navigation Bar should be shown on the left for Phone and Tablet, which can be opened by Burger-Menue-Button. For Desktop, the Navigation Bar is on the Top betweeen `<header>` and `<main>`

Thank you very much for your working example Code and your help :)
Have a nice Day :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use bootstrap Design to solve this Problem.

http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: No ... I want to use native CSS3 and HTML5 and the new Grid System.